# Does Live Class Reloading actually work when using Tapestry in IntelliJ IDEA CE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tapestry

I'm trying to learn Tapestry and I would like to use IDEA Community Edition instead of Eclipse but I can't understand if Live Class Reloading actually works there.
Following the instructions in "[Tapestry Tutorial](https://tapestry.apache.org/exploring-the-project.html)" (and adapting them to the IDEA create project using maven) I'm able to generate the Quickstart project. It runs fine with jetty:run but no LCR seems to take place.
I'm just simply changing a string in index.java page to see if it shows when reloading the page. I doesn't.
I tried manually building, rebuilding, compiling and saving files, single classes and whole project but no matter what I do, nothing happens to the reloaded page. It's stuck with the original value. Obviously if I stop and relaunch the change is immediately visible.
I'm using the vanilla project as it is. No additions or changes. I checked I'm not in production mode.

If I follow the same exact steps in Eclipse, it just works out of the box.

Comment: Please see if https://gist.github.com/naaman/1053217 helps

Comment: Thank you Egor. I tried the proposed setup. Everything starts and I can attach the remote debugger but still no LCR. I'm not even sure if this is a generic issue with HotSwapping or a specific to Tapestry's Live Class Reload. They are not the same thing but it seems strange to me that such a feature would not work on IDEA considering there has been a supported plugin till a few years back.

Comment: IntelliJ's build directory may be different than Maven, which is why you may not see live class reloading working.

You can confirm this in your setup if you search for `*.class` files in your project's directory. Or at the very least verify the timestamp for the `*.class` files you're expecting to live-reload.